# Fourier things-reference request

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, fourier-analysis

I'm looking for resources/references(books, websites, lectures) that cover everything Fourier: right from series(real, complex) to transforms, discrete transforms, and possibly modern topics like FFT.

Particularly, I'm interested in the various applications in image and signal processing, so something that covers this contextually is also much appreciated.

Comment: Digital Signal Processing by John G. Proakis and Dimitris G. Manolakis

Comment: @Mathxx that is quite an exhaustive book! I think electrical engineers actually follow that book in their undergrad.